# Core-Motion/accelerometer: Detecting when one edge of iPad lifts

Tags: ios, accelerometer, core-motion

I have recently completed a pitch training game.

Problem is that the game requires the user to make thousands of A/B/neither decisions, and I suffer from RSI so badly that I can't play it. I just about managed to code it. But it is too much tapping.

I would like to be able to sit the device on my lap and lift my left knee for A,  my right knee for B and both knees for ' neither '.

Is anyone aware of some code that would cut to the chase and save me having to mess around with raw accelerometer data?

Or is this a silly question?  Maybe it is just a few lines of code with this data?   Can anyone see it clearly?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a matter of just looking at the X axis on the accelerometer and tripping when it goes above or below a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

I expect you will need to detect more than one axis changing, but you will most likely end up doing the work yourself.

For some help you can look at [http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html.](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html)

But you may find that the `CMDeviceMotionObject` may meet your demands, so you can tell how the device is oriented:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html

That may be the simplest approach, I believe.